# Salesforce Auth Provider with Facebook SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, facebook, auth-provider

After 3 and a half days of reading through documentation and trial and error, I have come to a point where I am just stuck trying to make it so Community Users and/or normal Users can log into a salesforce org by using their FaceBook login credentials.

Has anybody had success with this where they can help me out?

I thought I had set up the Auth Provider correctly in Salesforce as well a Registration Handler class and also an App in Facebook, but when I try and use it for a fictitious Facebook account that should be tied to a Community User license in Salesforce I get an error along the lines of:

> There was a problem with your authentication attempt. Please try
>   again. If you continue to encounter problems, contact your
>   administrator.

I notice in the URL it has at the end `"AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=NO_ACCESS&ErrorDescription=User+was+a+portal+user"`.

Something tells me I am missing something really simple, but I am running out of things to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the Registration Handler code:

```
public class PortalHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler
{
    // createUser is called when there is no existing user linked 
    // to the incoming third party account
    public User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data)
    {
        User u;

        // Use incoming email for username, since we're working with a 
        // portal user
        List<User> l = [SELECT Id,UserName,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM User WHERE UserName = :data.email];
        if (l.size() > 0) 
        {
            u = l[0];
            System.debug('Found existing user record for '+ data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + ' ' + data.email);
            System.debug(u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName + ' ' + u.Email);

            // Update existing record
            u.Email = data.email;
            u.LastName = data.lastName;
            u.FirstName = data.firstName;
            // Useful to save the Facebook ID in a custom field
            //u.Facebook_ID__c = data.identifier;

            System.debug('Updating user record for '+ data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + ' ' + data.email);
            System.debug(u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName + ' ' + u.Email);

            update(u);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Portal users need an associated contact, which, in turn,
            // needs to be associated with an account.
            // For simplicity, just put all contacts on the sForce account
            Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name='Chapter ABC'];

            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.AccountId = a.Id;
            c.Email = data.email;
            c.FirstName = data.firstName;
            c.LastName = data.lastName;
            insert(c);

            u = new User();
            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='Customer Community User'];

            u.UserName = data.email;
            u.Email = data.email;
            u.LastName = data.lastName;
            u.FirstName = data.firstName;
            //u.Facebook_ID__c = data.identifier;
            u.Alias = (data.username != null) ? data.username : data.identifier;

            if (u.Alias.length() > 8) 
            {
                u.Alias = u.Alias.substring(0, 8);
            }

            u.Languagelocalekey = UserInfo.getLocale();
            u.Localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
            u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
            u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            u.ProfileId = p.Id;
            u.ContactId = c.Id;

            System.debug('Returning new user record for '+ data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + ' ' + data.email);

        }

        return u;
    }

    // updateUser is called when there is a match with an existing user
    public void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data)
    {
        User u = new User(Id=userId);

        u.Email = data.email;
        u.LastName = data.lastName;
        u.FirstName = data.firstName;
        //u.Facebook_ID__c = data.identifier;

        System.debug('Updating user record for '+ data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + ' ' + data.email);

        update(u);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, is it working now? I have a similar issue and I'm using the community parameter already however it is not redirecting me to the community and it is giving me the error: /AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=NO_ACCESS&ErrorDescription=User+was+an+internal+user+for+the+community . Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadaddy is on the right track here.  It's a bit nuanced, but here we go:

When logging into Salesforce you can really have multiple contexts.  The default is logging into the Org.  You do this from login.salesforce.com, your My Domain, or perhaps from an enterprise single sign-on service.  Here's where you access apps like Sales, Service, or custom apps on Force.com

You can also invite external users into your org.  Historically we called this a Portal - these days you do this through a Community.   It's a space that external users (customers, partners, etc) can login to and collaborate and be delivered applications, but can have separate authentication and authorization config from the core Org, which is sort of...employee only.

The Auth Provider URL you're using is setup, by default, to target the internal org.  So, when you use the SSO url on that page, it is trying to login to the Org, but since your Reg Handler creates a portal style user, they are blocked from logging in.

You can, of course, configure your Community to accept the Auth Provider.  This is a simple checkbox on the login configuration for the community, and it will automatically put a button on your Community login page, handle StartUrls, etc.

If you need to build the Auth Provider URL yourself to test manually, it's pretty easy...you just need a special param.   Here's an example:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000000FOO/Facebook?community=http%3A%2F%2Fcustomerdemo.force.com&startURL=

You just need to add that community param with your URL, plus an optional start url.   This will target the authentication to your community, instead of your org.

And once again, the Community login page does this for you automatically.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Chuck Mortimore, I think that did the trick. Thanks for taking the time to help explain that a little bit more.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you already have your Facebook user linked to a Salesforce Community (= Portal) user, and now you're trying to log him in as an internal user. A given FB user cannot be both.

To fix this, and test SSO as an internal user, you can break that user's link from FB to Salesforce. Log into the org as an admin, then go to that user's record, scroll down to **Third-Party Account Links** and hit **Revoke** against the Facebook link. Now your user should be able to login as an internal user.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding to me so quickly! Whether I revoke the third-party account link or not - I am still getting the same error.

I think I should clarify how I am trying to log them in (because you're making me think I am doing that wrong). For that specific Auth Provider, there are 5 Client Configuration links provided (Test-Only Initialization URL, Single Sign-On Initialization URL, Existing User Linking URL, Oauth-Only Initialization URL, and Callback URL).

I have been trying to use those links to log the user in based on their facebook account - is this wrong?

Comment: Based on the documentation I had been reading (http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_facebook.htm&language=en_US), it made me think I should be using those to login. Btw, I can tell from debug logs that the Registration Handler class does in fact find a match for that user based on their facebook credentials.

Comment: Yes - you should paste the callback URL into the Facebook app config. It sounds like you must have done that, otherwise it wouldn't be getting this far. Does the test init URL work? Can you post the code for your reg handler?

Comment: Yeah the test init URL works, and I added some system.debug parts to the Registration Handler so I know that is working (and also making this a little bit more frustrating haha).

Comment: Here is the Registration Handler code.. it was too long to simply paste here.. http://pastebin.com/HQmr1Bvd

Comment: I edited the code into the question for you. Nothing looks out of the ordinary to me. I'll ask @cmort to take a look...

Comment: Thank you for your help metadaddy, I believe I have it working now between everything you stated and Chuck Mortimore's help as well.