# Facebook Auth provider

Tags: community, auth-provider

Hello All,
               i had already created a Facebook App  Rex Demo and  i want to use  this app   through Single Sign on. 
Client Configuration:-
test-Only Initialization URL    https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/test/00DB000000018IzMAI/Facebook
Single Sign-On Initialization URL   https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00DB000000018IzMAI/Facebook
Existing User Linking URL   https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/link/00DB000000018IzMAI/Facebook
OAuth-Only Initialization URL   https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/oauth/00DB000000018IzMAI/Facebook
Callback URL    https://login.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/00DB000000018IzMAI/Facebook

After this  when i am using  open the call back url  and Test-Only Initialization URL on  my another browser  its not working . Help me out .

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser log?

Comment: @GauravKheterpal There was a problem with your authentication attempt. Please try again. If you continue to encounter problems, contact your administrator.

Comment: Are you trying to do a SSO to a Salesforce Community org?

Comment: @GauravKheterpal yes and   i am working on spring 15 pre release org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided, I suspect that your Auth Provider URL is not setup correctly. It needs to be in this format

https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000000FOO/Facebook?community=http%3A%2F%2Fcustomerdemo.force.com&startURL=

The important piece is the community param with your URL, plus an optional start url. This will target the authentication to your community, instead of your org.

You can read more details about how to configure and test on this thread [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/salesforce-auth-provider-with-facebook-sso).